# Find numbers of 8 characters inside a txt file

Tags: python, dev-c++

I have a text file of the size of 1 megabyte which contains some numeric strings and some letters strings with the characters length of 3, 5, 9, 8, 10. How can I find all the numbers that have only the length of 8 characters? And after finding the numbers with the length of 8 characters these numbers must be extracted and saved in this file extracted.txt . How i can do this?

Example...

**file.txt**

```
91664356
1665
00643
qouytyi
15790008
1567065
abcdeigf
qoiyytgxf
931467846
00851685
150033561246788
074226899
```

**extracted.txt**

```
91664356
15790008
15670654
00851685
```

Comment: Other than a regex?

Comment: Could you provide some sample data/lines from the input text file including positive and negative hits of "8 characters numbers"? Are accepted number format(s) int, hex, bin, float, ...?

Comment: Example...

file.txt 91664356 1665 00643 qouytyi 15790008 1567065 abcdeigf qoiyytgxf 931467846 00851685 150033561246788 074226899

extracted.txt 91664356 15790008 1567065 00851685

Comment: counted several times, but `1567065` seems to have only a length of seven. You stated `with the length of 8`. Please clarify.

Comment: 15670657 corrected with the lenght of 8

Answer (score 1):

Use -

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    data=myfile.read()

numbers = re.findall(r'\D(\d{8})\D', data)
```

It will catch numbers that have 8-length - which does *not* includes numbers like `478319.3`

It will output a list of such numbers.

**Example**

Let

`123.32 is a good number 12 also 12345678 478319.3`

be the contents of the file.
Output will be -

```
['12345678']
```

Comment: Any reason for `{8,8}` instead of `{8}`?

Comment: @DeepSpace just a flexibility so that if the user later decides to detect numbers between 8-10 chars in length he can do that. Using `{8}` might not let people reading this code lead to that

Comment: Also, this will provide wrong output for  the string `if you have a very long number it will match the first 8 digits, for example 123456781234`, which will extract `12345678`

Comment: @DeepSpace you are right I have modified the regex to now catch 8-length digits as OP suggested

Answer (score 0):

source file like this?
`12345678 123456789 1234567 abcdefg abcdefgh abcdefghi`
then,maybe this script can help you

```
f = open('stack.txt')
s = open('save.txt','w')
for i in f.read().split(' '):
    if(len(i)!=8):
        continue
    else:
        try:
            print(int(i))#if not number,int() will make an error
            s.write(i)
        except:
            pass
f.close()
s.close()
```